# Swift Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'Any' error?

Tags: swift

When trying to loop through the `terms` I'm getting an error of `Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'Any'` and was wondering what I'm doing wrong with they types?

Data:

```
        var terms: any Sequence = [["Monthly payment", "€919.99"],
                         ["Mileage per year", "15000 km"],
                         ["Cost per extra km", "€0.91"],
                         ["Refund per km not used","€0.30"],
                         ["Maximum refund","€1,000.00"]]
```

Code:

```
    func checkTerms(terms: any Sequence) {
        for (title, value) in terms {
            XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[title].exists)
            XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[value].exists)
        }
    }
```

Error:
`Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'Any'`

I expected to be able to use `title` and `value` in the loop to assert the information.

I get an error on typing of `Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'Any'`

Comment: That's really not how that works. There's no guarantee that `any Sequence` contains a tuple that can be destructed into a `title` and `value`.  Is there any reason you're not using a `[String: String]` dictionary for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not represent a basic understanding of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you chose 'any Sequence' as your variable type. Sequence is a protocol type that categorize any composition of elements.

When you declare your variable as:

```
var terms: any Sequence = [["Monthly payment", "€919.99"],
                         ["Mileage per year", "15000 km"],
                         ["Cost per extra km", "€0.91"],
                         ["Refund per km not used","€0.30"],
                         ["Maximum refund","€1,000.00"]]
```

The opaque type is: `[[String]]` and this mean that the inner arrays can have any length. Nothing guarantees that they will have two elements (Title and Value).

I think you can declare your variable as an array of Tuple.

```
var terms: [(String, String)] = [
        ("Montly payment", "€919.99"),
        ("Mileage per year", "15000 km")
]
```

And you can iterate on it like you want:

```
func checkTerms() {
        for (title, value) in terms {
            print(title, value)
        }
}
```